# SQL query, contar a quantidade de valores existentes de uma Foreign Key referentes a cada Primary Key correspondente em 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Exemplo com 2 tabelas:

```
table admin:
    columns: | id_admin | email | password |
    values:  |     1    | ex@ex |   123    |
             |     2   | ex2@ex2 |   123   |

table news:
    columns: | id_news  | title  | content | admin_id_admin |
    values:  |   1      |  ex    | cont    |       1        |
             |   2      |  ex2   | cont2   |       1        |
             |   3      |  ex3   | cont3   |       2        |
```

o que eu quero fazer:
    **Selecionar todos os dados de todos os admins e também a quantidade de news que cada um tem**

O retorno seria algo assim:

```
  | id_admin | email | password | count_news |
  |     1    | ex@ex |   123    |   2        |
  |     2   | ex2@ex2 |   123   |   1        |
```

Há alguma forma de realizar isso em uma query?

Como eu pensei na query:

```
 SELECT a.id_admin, a.email, a.password, COUNT(b.id_news) AS count_news FROM admin a, news b WHERE a.id_admin = b.admin_id_admin
```

Porém ele retorna "NULL" para todos os campos exceto para o "count_news".

Comment: se está usando o `count` no select, você precisa agrupar, está faltando um `group by a.id_admin, a.email, a.password` na sua query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta o `GROUP BY` na sua `query` e você pode utilizar um `JOIN` ao invés de colocar todas as tabelas no `FROM`:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
  id_admin INTEGER,
  email    VARCHAR(100),
  password VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO admin(id_admin, email, password)
           VALUES(1, 'ex@ex', '123'),
                 (2, 'ex2@ex2', '123');

CREATE TABLE news (
  id_news        INTEGER,
  title          VARCHAR(100),
  content        VARCHAR(100),
  admin_id_admin INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO news(id_news, title, content, admin_id_admin)
          VALUES(1, 'ex', 'cont', 1),
                (2, 'ex2', 'cont2', 1),
                (3, 'ex3', 'cont3', 2);
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT a.id_admin,
       a.email,
       a.password,
       COUNT(b.id_news) AS count_news
  FROM admin a
  LEFT JOIN news b ON a.id_admin = b.admin_id_admin
 GROUP BY a.id_admin, a.email, a.password;
```

---

**Resultado**

```
| id_admin | email   | password | count_news |
| -------- | ------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1        | ex@ex   | 123      | 2          |
| 2        | ex2@ex2 | 123      | 1          |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Precisa fazer um `INNER JOIN` entre as tabelas... Tenta assim...

```
SELECT a.id_admin, a.email, a.password, COUNT(b.admin_id_admin) AS count_news FROM admin a
INNER JOIN news b on b.admin_id_admin = a.id_admin WHERE a.id_admin = b.admin_id_admin
```

Comment: Ainda está retornando NULL para as colunas de "admin".